# How to resolve React Native onPress event not working

Tags: react-native

Native trying out new things, I have an image that is wrapped around TouchableOpacity, and added an onPress event however when I do try to press on that image I get not response back so I fail to understand where I really went wrong with my implementation

**Code below is what I tried to do**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";

export default class FloatingHomeButton extends Component {
  FloatingButtonEvent = () => {
    Alert.alert("Floating Button Clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={() => this.FloatingButtonEvent()}
          style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle}
        >
          <Image
            source={require("../images/button.png")}
            style={styles.FloatingButtonStyle}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#e5e5e5",
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  TouchableOpacityStyle: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
  },
  FloatingButtonStyle: {
    resizeMode: "contain",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 1100,
  },
});
```

Can I please get some help cause this is really not making sense to me why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind functions to `this` if you want to use class components. But you really should use function components now:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default function FloatingHomeButton() {
  const handleButtonPress = () => {
    Alert.alert('Floating Button Clicked');
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        onPress={handleButtonPress}
        style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle}
      >
        <Image source={require('../images/button.png')} style={styles.FloatingButtonStyle} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I literally did trying building a constructor and then have ```this.FloatingButtonEvent = this.FloatingButtonEvent.bind(this)```  to bind this function however still did not work. I even just took the code you gave before replying here and still the function is not getting triggered

Comment: Your original code works in this snack, with the exception that I removed the `marginTop` because that was a huge margin that was screwing everything up: https://snack.expo.io/@josmithua/trusting-chocolate

Comment: So if it works in the snack but doesn't work on your machine, that likely means that there's something wrong with your setup.

Comment: You think the problem could be by my expo on phone?

Comment: I don't see what else it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add zIndex into TouchableOpacityStyle

The problem may come from position absolute

Comment: Just tried adding a zIndex of 999 and still get the same results... If I may ask how could the position absolute be causing the problem?